# Loop through database query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to show the results of one database table by the use of a variable fetched from another database table like this:

```
mysql_select_db($database_Connection, $Connection);
$query_Recordset_bids = "SELECT * FROM bids WHERE bidder = '$userName'";
$Recordset_bids = mysql_query($query_Recordset_bids, $Connection) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row_Recordset_bids = mysql_fetch_array($Recordset_bids)) {
$totalRows_Recordset_bids = mysql_num_rows($Recordset_bids);

mysql_select_db($database_Connection, $Connection);
$query_Recordset_jobs = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE userID = '".$row_Recordset_bids['jobID']."'";
$Recordset_jobs = mysql_query($query_Recordset_jobs, $Connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset_jobs = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset_jobs);
$totalRows_Recordset_jobs = mysql_num_rows($Recordset_jobs);
}
```

And then I want the output showed in the following table:

```
<?php if($totalRows_Recordset_jobs == 0)
echo "You have never submitted a job offer!";
else {   
?>
<table width="440" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="tablejobs">
<tr>
    <th width="40" bgcolor="#779BDC" scope="col">ID</th>
    <th width="90" bgcolor="#779BDC" scope="col">Destination</th>
    <th width="85" bgcolor="#779BDC" scope="col">Cargo</th>
    <th width="85" bgcolor="#779BDC" scope="col">Due Date</th>
    <th width="75" bgcolor="#779BDC" scope="col">Bid</th>
    <th width="65" bgcolor="#779BDC" scope="col">Status</th>
</tr>
<?php do { ?>
  <tr>
    <td height="22" bgcolor="#798890" scope="col">&nbsp;<?php echo $row_Recordset_jobs['userID']; ?></td>
    <td bgcolor="#798890" scope="col">&nbsp;<?php echo $row_Recordset_jobs['destination']; ?></td>
    <td bgcolor="#798890" scope="col">&nbsp;<?php echo $row_Recordset_jobs['cargo']; ?></td>
    <td bgcolor="#798890" scope="col">&nbsp;<?php echo $row_Recordset_jobs['due_date']; ?></td>
    <td bgcolor="#798890" scope="col">&nbsp;<?php echo $row_Recordset_jobs['bids']; ?> kr.</td>
    <td bgcolor="#798890" scope="col">&nbsp;<?php echo $row_Recordset_jobs['status']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } while ($row_Recordset_jobs = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset_jobs)); ?>
 </table>
<?php
}
?>
```

But there is only one row shown in the table even though there are 2 or more results that match the select query.

So how do I loop through the first database table to get multiple matching variables (jobID) that I can use to my select statement to the second database table, which should show multiple results?

Comment: You can really use a JOIN query rather than using PHP to attempt the heavy lifting here. Obligatory PSA on changing from the deprected `mysql_` functions to either `mysqli_` or 'PDO`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to simply learn about joins. :)

You can also use a join on different databases aslong as both databases are available with the same connection/credentials.

I am not sure if I got you right that you have two databases for your tables.

If you have only one database its simple:

```
$query = 'SELECT * 
          FROM bids b 
          LEFT JOIN jobs j ON b.jobID = j.UserID 
          WHERE b.bidder = "$userName"';
```

Incase you have two databases use this and insert names of your two databases for <namedb1> and <namedb2>.

However, note that this is not the smartest thing to do because you cannot use any indizes, transactions, constraints or table-locks over different databases.
(As mentioned by Jay Blanchard in the comments)

```
$query = 'SELECT * 
          FROM <namedb1>.bids b 
          LEFT JOIN <namedb2>.jobs j ON b.jobID = j.UserID 
          WHERE b.bidder = "$userName"';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html

Comment: you can do joins from different database? I dont believe so

Comment: The OP said 'database table' @meda.

Comment: Oh, but you can still do joins over different databases, yes.

Comment: `the use of a variable fetched from another database table` , I dont think you can do that , but hey maybe I am wrong

Comment: Just a hunch, but I think the OP is referring to two tables in the same database, especially since his `select_db` statements are the same.

Comment: @JayBlanchard no, so why he used `mysql_select_db` twice

Comment: @Steini regardless of the possibility joining (it's not really joining) tables from disparate databases it really isn't a desirable thing to do in practice.

Comment: Aslong as both databases are located in the same server and are accessible with the same auth credentials you can easily join even over databsaes by using the database name seperated with a dot "." from the table name. FROM db1.tbl a LEFT JOIN db2.tbl b ON a.colx = b.coly

Comment: @JayBlanchard, Well I did this with perfect results already. If "its not a good thing in practice" it might also be bad to seperate the data in two databases in the first place.

Comment: @meda because the OP is not experienced in doing this type of thing the selections is done twice, but with the same variables.

Comment: @Steini I am not saying it cannot be done, but I am saying that in larger systems you will run into problems due to lack of foreign key contraints, locking and other conditions. In the realm of true normalization you would never do this. It indicates that the system is badly designed.

Comment: You except a big system to be behind that code? I know its not the best thing to do but that is something that should be cared about when designing the database itself. But this merely looks like a hobby project. And for this matter I think the advise is okay. Who doesnt know about joins and codes like that did rather not even place any indizes in the database. I agree with your concern that its not the best solution but I think it will fit here. Oh and by the way the expression "database table" doesnt necessarily mean that there are two databases. It can be a bad description of the scheme.

Comment: @Steini Thanks for the suggestion. It worked. BUT I have a following question: How do I add another select statement to your suggested code? I want to add a variable from a column of the bids table